# Retrieving Timestamp from Oracle Akka Persistence in akka.net

Tags: c#, akka, actor, akka.net

I am using Akka.net with [oracle persistence](https://github.com/ismaelhamed/akka.persistence.oracle).

Now I need to create a projection from my aggregate events and I need the timestamp on which the event occurred.

Unfortunately, I did not add this property to the event.

However, looking ate the EventJournal table used by the persistence, there is a timestamp column

[image]

But I cannot seem to be able to access it in a PersistentQuery stream:

```cs
 Source<EventEnvelope, NotUsed> stream =  
     PersistenceQuery
    .Get(_system)
    .ReadJournalFor<SqlReadJournal>(SqlReadJournal.Identifier)
    .EventsByTag(_myTag, 0L);
```

Because `EventEnvelope` does not have this property in it.

Does anyone knows if there is a way to get the timestamp o my projection ?

Comment: The equivalent class in Scala (`akka.persistence.query.EventEnvelope`) does have `timestamp` field, so I am guessing you're out of luck and will need to raise issue with maintainers of akka for .net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Akka net 1.4.14, a Timestamp property has been added to the `EventEnvelope`. So it is no longer a problem.